# How remove whitespace characters in value field mongodb

Tags: mongodb

this is my example object in MongoDB database:

```
{
  _id:"61e6c21d84df6644d9833382",
  Moc:"170 KM",
  Napęd:"Na przednie koła",
  Kolor:"Inny kolor",
  Marka_pojazdu:"Mitsubishi",
  Model_pojazdu:"ASX",
  Pojemność_skokowa:"2 400 cm3",
  Typ_nadwozia:"SUV",
  Liczba_drzwi:"5",
  Rodzaj_paliwa:"Benzyna",
  Skrzynia_biegów:"Automatyczna",
  Liczba_miejsc:"5"
}
```

I want to change `Pojemność_skokowa:"2 400 cm3"` to `Pojemność_skokowa:"2400"`, how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Pojemnosc_skokowa: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $slice: [
              { $split: [ "$Pojemnosc_skokowa", " " ] },
              0,
              { $add: [ { $size: { $split: [ "$Pojemnosc_skokowa", " " ] } }, -1 ] }
            ]
          },
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xGZnRggln9e)

Answer (score 0):

Query

- replaceAll " " with "" to remove all whitespace
- substrCP to take the string except the last 3 characters to remove the "cm3"

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71369651-m)

```js
update({},
[{"$set":
  {"Pojemność_skokowa":
   {"$replaceAll":
    {"input":"$Pojemność_skokowa",
     "find":" ",
     "replacement":""}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"Pojemność_skokowa":
   {"$substrCP":
    ["$Pojemność_skokowa", 0,
     {"$subtract":
      [{"$subtract":
        [{"$strLenCP":"$Pojemność_skokowa"}, 3]}, 0]}]}}}])
```